# rethinkdb match inside an array

Tags: arrays, match, rethinkdb

I have a table called 'conditions' which contains JSON documents structured as such:

```
{
 "keyA": "valueA",
 "keyB": "valueB",
 "symptoms": ["foobar", "bar", "cough", "itch"]
}
```

I simply would like to execute a query which returns all documents that have symptoms which match a regex.

The closest I have gotten is with this query:

```
r.db('database_name').table('conditions').filter(r.row('symptoms').nth(0).match('oob'));
```

This would return the document (row) since it matches with the 0th element "foobar".

However I'm simply unable to figure out a way to iterate over the whole array. E.g. if "foobar" were to be the last element in the "symptoms" array it wouldn't match.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Edit: I figured it out by myself. Heres the query that works:

```
r.db('database_name').table('conditions').filter(function(row){
  return row('symptoms').contains(function(symptom){
     return symptom.match('foo')
  })
})
```